# Infinite scroll and will_paginate appending the 'next page' of items multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, will-paginate

I am following [this railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/114-endless-page-revised) in trying to implement an infinite scroll page on my rails app. When a user scrolls down to the bottom of the page an new set of items is appended and the page extends, however it is appended to the page multiple times and the event triggers again on scrolldown even when all the items in the array have been loaded, appending the same set of items again multiple times.

What I would like is to append the 'next page' of items each time a user scrolls to the bottom, and subsequent next pages as the user scrolls to the bottom again.

Here is the jQuery for this function:

```
jQuery ->
  if $('.pagination').length
          $(window).scroll ->
                  url = $('.pagination .next_page').attr('href')
                  if url &&  $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 50
                      $('.pagination').text('Fetching more products...')
                      $.getScript(url)
$(window).scroll()
```

and here is the corresponding javascript

```
$('#products').append('<%= j render(@products) %>');
<% if @products.next_page %>
    $('.pagination').replaceWith('<%= j will_paginate(@products) %>');
<% else %>
    $('.pagination').remove();
<% end %>
```

Comment: You can use [Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/), it's very good

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code will trigger a `$.getScript(url)` call when the user scrolls to 50px from the bottom. Then another call at if they scroll to 49px from the bottom. Then another if they scroll to 48px from the bottom and this will continue until one of the AJAX calls returns and makes the page taller; once the page is taller, you'll be outside the 50px zone and the *Fetching more products...* will stop.

You only want one `getScript` going at a time. Once they scroll into the 50px zone, you want to fetch some more stuff from the server (just once) then ignore subsequent scrolls until the server has responded.

You should be doing something more like this:

```
$(window).scroll ->
    # Bail out right away if we're busy loading the next chunk.
    return if(window.pagination_loading)

    url = $('.pagination .next_page').attr('href')
    if url &&  $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 50
        # Make a note that we're busy loading the next chunk.
        window.pagination_loading = true

        # Load as before but attach a callback to clear the flag when we're done.
        $('.pagination').text('Fetching more products...')
        $.getScript(url).always -> window.pagination_loading = false
```

[`$.getScript`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) returns a [`jqXHR`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) and the `jqXHR`'s [`always`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.always/) callbacks will be called when the underlying `$.ajax` call is finished.

Comment: Thank you, this fixed my problem locally,however when deployed through heroku the endless page function ceases to work and does not append the next page at all. Any ideas on what may be causing this issue? Thanks again for your help

Comment: @allareri: Is `getScript` getting called? Is the server-side controller getting called? Any JavaScript errors or warnings in the console? Have you tried attaching an error callback to the `$.getScript` call?

Comment: @muistooshort I was having the same similar issue and followed your above suggestion. However now the infinite scrolling does not work because the `if condition` is not satisfied because the `url` returned is undefined. If you could take a look at my gist please: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e6b56f1bccf754a865eb

Comment: @user532339: Do you still have a `.pagination .next_page` element? Does it have an `href` attribute?

Comment: @muistooshort I managed to get it working I had to just to reference the `a` link. However interestingly the infinite scroll works now but it seems to still return duplicate records. I.e. if a set of a records are ordered by `id` in ascending order when you scroll to the end of the set of records it repeats them again. FYI this is using your above suggested solution.

Comment: @muistooshort This is a long shot. But I noticed that as you get to the end of the set of records (where its about to repeat again) the `url` changes from  `/challenges?_=1431347899290&page=5` to `#` so what I have done is added an additional check above if statement that says `if url != #` and this seems to work

Comment: @muistooshort how do i write `return if(window.pagination_loading)` and `$.getScript(url).always -> window.pagination_loading = false` in jquery? thanks.

Comment: @TimmyVonHeiss: You mean in JavaScript? Have a look at the "TRY COFFEESCRIPT" tab at http://coffeescript.org.

Comment: I used http://js2.coffee/ to convert from coffee to js.  Here is the code if anyone wants it: `if (window.pagination_loading) {
    return;
  }` and `$.getScript(url).always(function() {
            return window.pagination_loading = false;
        });`

Comment: however, this did not help me for my question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38413955/jquery-load-more-button-and-then-infinite-scrolling-in-rails-app.