# Rails 3: endless scrolling stuck on 'fetching more posts' but terminal shows page 2 was fetched and rendered all partials

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, will-paginate

I'm implementing code from railscast 114 (revised) for endless scrolling. I have it setup but the jquery message gets stuck on 'fetching more posts.' However, my logs show the page was fetched and the partials were rendered from my js.html.erb file. Why is the data from page 2 (@feed_items) not being inserted into my div#stream? Also the log shows a large amount of SELECT for the /_like_form.html.erb partial which appears to be incorrect.

Where in this workflow and I making a mistake? This question would apply in general to anyone making endless scrolling from will_paginate gem where the collection of items) (@feed_items is not the same name as the controller name (PagesController#home). Thank you very much for any insights into this issue.

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
   respond_to :html, :js
  def home
    @title = "Home"

    if user_signed_in?
      @user = current_user
      @post = current_user.posts.build
      @authentications = @user.authentications
      @stream_title = "Posts" 
      @feed = @user.feed
      @feed_items = @feed.paginate(:per_page => "10", :page => params[:page])
      respond_to do |format|
         format.html { render "pages/home" }
         format.js { render "pages/home"}
      end
   end
```

pages/home.js.erb

```
$('#stream').append('<%= j render(@feed_items) %>');
<% if @feed_items.next_page %>
  $('.pagination').replaceWith('<%= j will_paginate(@feed_items) %>');
<% else %>
  $('.pagination').remove();
<% end %>
```

pages/home.html.erb

```
 <div id="stream">  
      <%= render 'shared/feed'%>
 </div>
```

shared/feed.html.erb

```
<% unless @feed_items.empty? %>
  <%= render :partial => 'shared/feed_item', :collection => @feed_items %>
  <%= will_paginate @feed_items %>
<% end %>
```

shared/feed_item.html.erb

```
<div id="post-item<%= "_"+ feed_item.id.to_s%>" class="post-item">
  <div class="post-user">  
    <%= link_to small_avatar_for(feed_item.user), feed_item.user, 
            :class => "post-avatar" %>
    <div class="post-user-info">        
    <%= link_to feed_item.user.name, feed_item.user,
        :class => "post-name" %>
    <a href="<%= user_path(feed_item.user) %>" class="post-username">@<%= feed_item.user.username%></a> 
    </div>  
  </div>
  <a class="post-image">
    <%= thumb_post_image_for(feed_item)%>
  </a>
  <div class="post-message">
    <%= feed_item.title %>
  </div> 
  <div class="post-buttons"> 
    <% if user_signed_in? %>     
      <%= render :partial => 'users/like_form', :locals => { :post => feed_item } %>
    <% else %>
      <div class="btn-sign-in"><a href="<%= new_user_session_path %>">Like</a></div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

posts/_post.html.erb

```
<%= render :partial => 'shared/feed_item', :collection => @feed_items %>

<%= will_paginate @feed_items %>
```

javascripts/application.js

```
jQuery(function() {
  if ($('.pagination').length) {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      var url;
      url = $('.pagination .next_page').attr('href');
      if (url && $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 50) {
        $('.pagination').text("Fetching more posts...");
        return $.getScript(url);
      }
    });
  }
  return $(window).scroll();
});
```

LOG (FULL: http://pastie.org/9834710)

```
Started GET "/?page=2&_=1421389772215" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-16 13:29:32 +0700
  Processing by PagesController#home as JS
  Parameters: {"page"=>"2", "_"=>"1421389772215"}
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 31 LIMIT 1
  Post Load (7.0ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE (user_id IN (SELECT followed_id FROM relationships
 WHERE follower_id = 31) OR user_id = 31) ORDER BY posts.created_at DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10
  SQL (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "posts" WHERE (user_id IN (SELECT followed_id FROM relationships
 WHERE follower_id = 31) OR user_id = 31)......
.......
Rendered users/_like.html.erb (1.0ms)
Rendered users/_like_form.html.erb (2.4ms)
Rendered shared/_feed_item.html.erb (45.2ms)
Rendered posts/_post.html.erb (674.0ms)
Rendered pages/home.js.erb (686.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1018ms (Views: 651.8ms | ActiveRecord: 48.9ms)
```

Comment: see this question, the answer will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13555101/infinite-scroll-and-will-paginate-appending-the-next-page-of-items-multiple-ti

Comment: thank you, I looked at that post and tried using the following code instead but the same results are occurring `$(window).scroll(function() {
  var url;
  if (window.pagination_loading) {
    return;
  }
  url = $('.pagination .next_page').attr('href');
  if (url && $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 50) {
    window.pagination_loading = true;
    $('.pagination').text('Fetching more products...');
    return $.getScript(url).always(function() {
      return window.pagination_loading = false;
    });
  }
});`