# Endless Scrolling gives template error on scrolling down to next page

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, infinite-scroll, will-paginate

I have done pagination using will_paginate gem now I want endless scrolling using this gem only and I have followed [railcast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/114-endless-page) and this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13555101/infinite-scroll-and-will-paginate-appending-the-next-page-of-items-multiple-ti?rq=1) link and written all the codes regarding this. The problem is data comes fine but it is repeating many times on the page when I scroll down to it. I don't know why it is giving this. Any help will be appreciable.

My Controller Code :

```
def locations
    merchants = Merchant.where("role = ?", 'Merchant')
    @merchants_data = merchants.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 20)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
  end
```

**_location.html.erb :**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>
      Name
    </th>
  </tr>
  <% @merchants_data.each do |x| %>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <%= x.name %>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>

<%= will_paginate @merchants_data %>
```

**home.js.coffee :**

```
jQuery ->
if $('.pagination').length 
  $(window).scroll ->
    url = $('.pagination .next_page').attr('href')
    if url &&  $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 50
      $('.pagination').text('Fetching more locations...')
      $.getScript(url)
  $(window).scroll()
```

**location.js.erb :**

```
$('#locations').append('<%= j render partial: "locations", collection:@merchants_data %>');
<% if @merchants_data.next_page %>
  $('.pagination').replaceWith('<%= j will_paginate(@merchants_data) %>');
<% else %>
  $('.pagination').remove();
<% end %>
```

Comment: errormessage is what?

Comment: @huanson It is giving ActionView::MissingTemplate error.

Comment: sorry but its so stupid to say the exception_class !you already said its missing template. obviously we (or i) asked for the path its throwing,  so which template he is looking for and cant find. ;)

Comment: I have render the partials and got the data but still the problem is that the data is repeating several times.

Answer (score 0):

In your `location.js.erb` you are doing `render @merchants_data` which will expect that there is a partial `_merchant.html.erb` which it will render for each `Merchant` instance in that data. I expect that that is the template which rails is looking for, not finding, and reporting an error for. There are more details in the [rails guide on layouts and rendering](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials) under "Rendering collections".

So, you need to either provide a partial to render a merchant or do your rendering slightly differently (too many options to mention).

You may have other issues in there too though. I don't see anything in your html with `id="locations"` so it will struggle to append any rendering to that.

Comment: I have solved that problem now it is displaying the next page record but now it is repeating the same elements on every scroll and when we reaches to the bottom of the page than again data comes from third page but the same record is repeating every time until it reaches to the bottom of the page.

Comment: Sounds like a new question then. And if you've solved the problem then you should post and answer explaining what the solution was.

Comment: The problem didn't get solve. I got the data on the page but the data is repeating when I scroll down to go the next page.